# linux/xfce4: screensaver stopped working, seeming idle detection issue

Tags: xfce, screensaver

I'm using xfce4 under ubuntu with the 4.15.0.30 kernel.

Starting yesterday after a number of reboots, the screensaver (I'm using `xscreensaver`) stopped getting invoked when the system is idle.

- `xscreensaver` is definitely running
- When I issue `xscreensaver-command activate` the screensaver starts successfully
- When I close the laptop lid and reopen, `xscreensaver` comes up properly with a lock screen.
- The screensaver is enabled within the xfce4 settings panel and set to blank after 3 minutes. No matter what value I use for "Blank after", the screen saver never automatically pops up.
- I can issue a `Preview` of the screensaver within the settings panel, and it works.
- I have completely uninstalled and reinstalled `xscreensaver` and completely reset all of its settings. This did not fix the problem.
- I have rebooted several times, and this did not fix the problem, either.

My guess is that this isn't a problem with `xscreensaver` or its configuration, but rather, it's as if  my system is no longer detecting that it is in an idle state. How do I test and diagnose this? What factors can cause my system to stop realizing that it is idle?

I made a change in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` yesterday. I entered this setting:

```
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=15s
```

... and then I issued `systemctl daemon-reload` and rebooted. All other entries in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` are commented out. Thinking that this might be causing the problem, I commented out that setting again, ran `systemctl daemon-reload` again, and then followed that by a reboot. But the same screensaver problems continued.

Any ideas of what might be causing my system to not detect that it is idle, and how this might be fixed?

Thank you in advance.